# Why is it that whenever I visit almost any high profile site it asks me to install something?

Tags: unity, webapps

When I go to facebook.com my browser says to install facebook messenger, youtube asks me to install youtube and android authority and such ask to install some...something. When I say I do want to install it it doesn't do anything so it has really become just some annoying popup. is there some way I can change this? Why is it doing it in the first place?

Comment: I think these are just the web apps ? Install one then reboot and then search in the dash for it

Comment: What does this have to do with ubuntu? It does this on all OSes. The reason is they want facebook to be in your vision as much as possible because then you see their adverts. What browser is this?

Comment: it seems it actually was specific to linux, ubuntu mainly...I was using firefox. Many sites seem to ask to add webapps to unity so I checked there and it showed all the ones I had added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "popups" are used to add extra functionality to the unity desktop manager. I personally dislike them but there are quite a few people who want to be able to use facebook without going to facebook.

You are using firefox correct??
If that is not the case comment and I'll change the top part of my answer.

Open Firefox>Preference. In the "General" tab you see "prompt integration options for any website". Uncheck it and you're done.

[image: screenshot of option to deselect]

Or you can do it in Ubuntu preferences: open dconfig editor and expand the following labels: com -> cononical -> unity -> webapps and untick "integration allowed"
[image: dconfig editor]

Comment: Or via CLI: `gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps integration-allowed false`

Comment: true, true. Whatever method you prefer is correct. Personally I like to see what I'm doing and what other things are present inside the same branch of the almighty tree of settings but in the end it all boils down to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

These are [Unity Webapps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/web/):

> Ubuntu webapps are web-hosted sites or apps that are displayed inside an Ubuntu app container. They are true apps that users install, see, launch and use. But their content is provided through URLs.

Webapps create Launcher icons and provide other features to some websites. They used to be simple launchers for Firefox, with some custom options (like "Compose" for GMail). However, they apparently use the Ubuntu Browser (called [Oxide](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=196)) from 14.04 onwards, according to this [OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04) and this [Ubuntu Discourse discussion](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/webapps-broken-and-behaviour-hobbled-in-14-04/1633/12), but do provide more features.